# Esper rule language: return datafield of class from pattern

Tags: java, rules, rule-engine, complex-event-processing, esper

I have the following rule that fires when the heart rate remains above 160 for 5 minutes.

```
EPStatement cepStatementRule3 = cepRule.createEPL("context PartitionByMacHeartRate "
                + "select * from pattern[every(HeartRate(heartrate > 160) "
                + "-> (timer:interval(5 min) "
                + "and not HeartRate(heartrate<=160)))]");
        cepStatementRule3.addListener(new rule3Listener());
```

My HeartRate class has the following fields:

```
int heartrate;
String heartratesTimestamp;
String macAddress;
```

What I want is to be able to get the macAddress in my ruleListener. This however
returns an empty hashmap. So my question is how can I return the macAddress of the HeartRate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patterns retain and return the tagged events, i.e. this would do:

```
// we assign the 'h' tag to the first event and the engine now retains that
// the select clause could use "h.macAddress as macAddress", for example
...every(h=HeartRate(...
```